# Confusion with when is asking about impure mass of the component and pure mass

Tags: stoichiometry

I've had this problem just to illustrate my confusion better:

> An impure mixture of $Fe_2O_3$ that reacts with commercial $HCl$ with a density of $1.19 g/mL$, that contains a 35% of mass of the pure acid.
> a) Find the percentage of pure $Fe_2O_3$ if 5 grams of this component react exactly with 10mL of the acid.

One of my main confusion is if the density given will be of the pure or impure mass, but I decided it to be referring to the pure mass, same with the volume, I assumed they were talking about pure volume of the component. **Please let me know if this is wrong logic**. So with what I said: $$m_{pure}=d_{pure}V_{pure}$$ and then since I assumed that $m_{pure}=0.35m_{total}$ then $$m_{total}=0.35d_{pure}V_{pure}$$ plugging the info above: $$m_{total}=4.165g \text{ of } HCl$$ then here comes another one of my big conceptual questions:

When you operate between **different** components, are you reacting with the $m_{total}$ or with the $m_{pure}$ mass of, in this case, $HCl$?

I assumed you react with the whole $m_{total}$? **Please do let me know if this is wrong logic**. Then with what I just assumed: $$\frac{159.6g \ Fe_2O_3}{219g \ HCl}=\frac{x \ g \ Fe_2O_3}{4.165g\ HCl}\implies x=3.035g \text{ of the total impure }Fe_2O_3$$ and hence $\%=\frac{3.03}{5}\cdot 100=60\%$ the fun fact is that I get the correct answer, but the logic I used seems completely flawed and what confused me most, is that I even contradict myself at some times I think, specially at the end since the formula is pure over impure and not otherwise, but still gets me the correct answer. Anyone can shine a light on all my questions, specially the ones I specifically wrote in bold?

*Please don't post an alternative solution, I already have tons of those, just want to solve my doubts with the method I just mentioned and all the questions I wrote, thanks.*

Comment: The density relates to the acid solution, it has no relation to purity/impurity.

Comment: I am sorry, your approach is quite incorrect and this is why you are confused. However, at the end you state that you do not want an alternative solution, which would be the rational solution.

Comment: "35% of pure acid" is misleading expression, there is no such thing as pure HCl acid. HCl is a gas.

Comment: @Poutnik okay that's clearer, what about the second question I wrote in bold?

Comment: Dear editors, please refrain from incomplete edits. Especially serial ones, and *especially* to the posts of new users. This causes more harm than good because it bumps the question to the main page over and over again and the question, still not being properly corrected properly, attracts downvotes and annoys other users. Instead, make a single solid edit that does it all for OP and community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Poutnik has been hinting at, density has no relationship with the purity of an HCl solution. There are density vs. concentration tables for acids but you don't need them. From the density, you *cannot* extract the moles of HCl directly. You will have to go through the molarity route and life will become much easier.

Also, ignore the 35% pure acid statment, probably that is adding more problems. It is a very simple problem and the logic is as follows. You will see where density of the acid is used.

You have 35% w/w HCl solution (the question should specify weight/weight). All that means is in 100 g of acid solution, you have 35 g HCl (dissolved gas, Mol. wt 36.458) or 35 /36.458  = 0.96 moles of HCl.

Now we need molarity of the HCl solution: We know the solution mass, and we know the solution density, 1.19 g/mL.

The volume of 100 g of acid solution = 100 g/1.19 g/mL = 84 mL

The molarity of HCl solution is 0.96 moles/ 0.084 L = 11. 43 M.

Now write a balanced equation between $\ce{Fe2O3}$ and HCl, and see what the products should be.

From the balanced equation determine the moles of HCl consumed  ( Molarity= moles/Volume)!

From the stoichiometric coefficients, determine the moles and hence the mass of $\ce{Fe2O3}$.

Comment: −1 for 1. jargonic and physically wrong term "moles" for the amount of substance; 2. improperly modified unit symbol (% w/w); 3. incorrect abbreviation "Mol. wt"; 4. missing units; 5. inconsistent spacing; 6. "textual" formulas; 7. half of the answer is not the answer, rather directions and suggestions that should've been sorted out in the comment prior to posting.